# Enabling SSL Client Certificates on IISExpress

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, iis-express

I'm trying to setup a development environment on my machine for an ASP.NET MVC project where client certificates are requested when trying to reach certain controllers.

I've enabled SSL on the project through project properties on VS Studio, I've also imported IISExpress self-signed certificate into trusted CAs in my browser and the client certificate into personal certificates in the browser.

Now, when I try to reach the controller where the certificate is requested, my browser opens a list to select the appropiate certificate, but the certificate matching the IISExpress one doesn't appears in the list, although it's on the certification store on the browser.

Any idea about what to do next?

Comment: Which client certificate do you refer to? The IIS Express certificate is for server usage only.

Comment: I've discovered that yesterday :(, how then can I test the client certificate sending to the server? At this moment the server asks for a client certificate, but I haven't anyone valid to send

Comment: makecert command can be used to create self signed certificates. Search for articles on that at MSDN for WCF and you can see lots of examples.